# calling a method inside a class from a different file

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I am trying to implement python classes and objects in my application code. Currently, I have a file that includes all the frequently used functions. I import them in another file.

funcs.py

```
class name1():

     def func1(x):

         return x

     def func2(y):

         return y

....
```

file1.py

```
from funcs import func1
from funcs import func2
```

I'd like to organize the code in class, method and attributes and then invoke them in different files.

How do I call a method within a class from another file? What changes do I need to make in `funcs.py` file?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me -- *there are no classes in the examples you provided*. In any case, you call a method **the same way you always do**, on an instance of that class. So, consider you have an instance of the `list` class, `mylist = list(range(10))`, now you want to call a method on it, so you can do `mylist.append(99)`. This always works exactly the same

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i updated the post with a class.

Comment: That is not a correct class definition. in any case, what part of calling a method do you not understand? I'm not trying to be mean, but it sounds like you want us to explain to you how class definitions work completely starting from the ground up.

Comment: Like, you can't jsut nest your function definitions inside of a class definition. Well, you can, but if you do that, you might as well remove the class definition and stick with the functions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga classes, objects are a little new to me. So, I am trying to wrap my head around it. I only have function definitions in my file and need to implement a class structure.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is way too broad of a question. You should start by reading some [basic materials, like the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method within a class, first you have to instantiate an object of that class, and then call the method in reference to the object. Below is not an ideal implementation but it's just for example. 
**example.py**

```
class MyClass:
    def my_method(self):
        print('something')

object1 = MyClass()
object1.my_method()
```

Then when you want to call the method in another file you have to first import them.

 **another.py**

```
from .example import MyClass

object2 = MyClass()
object2.my_method()
```

If you just want to call the method without having to create an object first you can use `@staticmethod`.

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def my_method(self):
        print('something')

MyClass.my_method()
```

Yet as I said this is not the ideal implementation. As @juanpa.arrivillaga said ideally you cannot just throw in any method and bundle them into a single class. The content of a class is all related to the object you want to define as a class.